# ASP.NET MVC controller accept javascript object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

From chrome developer tools I see that my request is sending this info to my controller:

```
models:[{"Id":null,"Start":"2014-06-11T12:17:52.452Z","End":"2014-06-11T12:17:52.452Z","Name":"test","Status":"test"}]
```

How can I accept it in my MVC controller?

It looks like to be a javascript array with one element.

On serverside I have method accepting :  `Foo(Bar models)` and also tried `Foo(List<Bar> models)`

The models value is always `null`. Any suggestions, how to get the value to my server?

Comment: It would be better if you post the code that send this string to the controller instead.

Comment: How is this being passed (AJAX?) You may need to specify the `dataType` parameter so MVC knows it's JSON incoming and not just a string value.

Comment: @BradChristie I have `dataType: "json"` and its weird, when I change my controller to accept `Foo(object models)` the object is a list that contains a string `"[{\"Id\":null,\"StartDate\":\"2014-06-11T13:08:19.483Z\",\"EndDate\":\"2014-06-11T13:08:19.483Z\",\"Name\":\"test\",\"Status\":\"test\"}]"`, it seems like ModelBinding is broken or something, since when I put real model, I get null.

Comment: @Jaanus: Give me a few moments, putting together working example for you. (And I assume this is AJAX, correct?)

Comment: This is ajax, yes. btw if it gives more info, using kendo grid inline item creation. http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline , this is the request from chrome dev tools. maybe something wrong with headers http://pastebin.com/Yj1sckq0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to pass the information using AJAX, you need to supply two parameters: `dataType` and `contentType`. (I suppose `dataType` is optional, but if you're expecting JSON back it's better to supply it.). The `contentType`, however, lets MVC [the `ModelBinder`] know the incoming request isn't just a string, but that it's an object that needs to be deserialized back into objects.

with that said, something like the following should work for your circumstance:

```
// This is your to-be-sent data'
// However you collect it, but for now we're storing it as a plain object.
var jso = { models: [{ "Id": null, "Start": "2014-06-11T12:17:52.452Z", "End": "2014-06-11T12:17:52.452Z", "Name": "test", "Status": "test" }] }

// Here we turn it into JSON
var json = JSON.stringify(jso);

// And now we send it off to the controller/action:
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction","SomeController")',
  type: 'POST',
  data: json, // pass of data serialized
  dataType: 'json', // expecting json back
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', // hey ModelBinder, deserialize this!
})/* handle the Deferred callbacks (.done, .fail, .always) */;
```

Then, in your controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SomeAction(IList<MyModel> models)
    {
         // Should pass now
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             // Handle it and return back the response
             // Given the above, you have something like the following now
             // assigned to "models":
             // models = new List<MyModel> {
             //   new MyModel {
             //     Id = null,
             //     Start = new DateTime(2014, 11, 6, 12, 17, 52),
             //     End = new DateTime(2014, 11, 6, 12, 17, 52),
             //     Name = "test",
             //     Status = "test"
             //   }
             // };

             return Json(new {Models = models }); // just to see it come back
         }
         return Json(new { Error = true, Message = "Invalid model" });
    }
}
```

Working example can be seen [On GitHub](https://github.com/bchristie/StackOverflow-Examples/tree/question-24162865) by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple example using POST and Json.Net to deserialize into a JObject

Get Json.Net via Nuget.

API Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic UpdateItem([FromBody]dynamic item)
{
    var qp = JObject.Parse(item.ToString());
    string oid = qp.SelectToken("oid").ToString();

...
```

Make sure your route and param name matches an actual route, for example

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "ItemApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{item}",
   defaults: new { item = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Usually found under App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs or in global.asax.

And then post to it using jquery ajax:

```
var param = new Object();
param.oid = "somestring";
param.name = "john";
param.number = 3;            
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/YourController/UpdateItem",
    data: JSON.stringify(param),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data) {
        // do stuff
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.error("error", e);                    
    }
});
```

EDIT: I see now that you are using a mvc controller. I assumed a webapi controller for my answer. Apologizes :)

Comment: Once again, the `ModelBinder` is fully capable of deserializing incoming JSON data (without the need to process it yourself in an action or (moreover) add another dependency to do so). IMHO, coming up with alternatives to deserializing the information outside of the `ModelBinder` adds unnecessary complexity, maintenance headaches and is just more work than is needed.

Comment: It's a matter of taste isn't it? in this solution you wouldn't have to create a poco, which can be handy and appropriate sometimes

Comment: And what if you decide to rename a property, or change a data type?  Not going to have the luxury of compiler errors.  Instead you wind up chasing your tail, or worse, come across the errors in production.

Comment: See my edit, I would probably use a strongly typed model if this were a strongly typed view posting to a mvc controller. As for web api, it's a matter of taste and scenario imo. I could put the property names of the dynamic object in a json schema or config... what you suggest / using poco would also work ;-)

Comment: Understood. I just feel like solidified models are the best route. Sure, they can be extra overhead (especially when you're dealing with such little pieces of information) but, then again, we'd be working in "VC" instead of "MVC" if we didn't use them. ;-) (As an aside, you'd be amazed how fast problems can manifest using `dynamic`. Probably one of the biggest reasons behind TypeScript given JavaScript's "looseness").

Comment: I agree in many (most?) cases, but there are times when I would use a dynamic, one example would be proxies to bypass cors, where you don't necessarily know how the request will look like... Oh well, getting off-topic now... :)

Answer (score 0):

It is mvc's default behaviour it will convert json object to your C# object automatically. just makesure property name matches. Check this may help

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to use **JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()** method.

Like this

```
List<YourModelClass> myObjList = 
(List<YourModelClass>)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(models, typeof(List<test>));
```

Then return this object named - **myObjList** to your view or whatever...

And For single object -

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModelClass>(models);
```

Comment: Default behavior of the `Modelbinder` is to do this. no need for an explicit call (unless it varies greatly outside the scope of the `ModelBinder`, in which case you can implement your own `IModelBinder`)